# C macro: How to use macro to generate parameters list of another macro

Tags: c, macros

I have a lot of lines of code like below:

```
     sp_setup_point( setup, get_vert(vertex_buffer, i-0, stride) );
```

for each of them, I want to be able to extract (i-0) and pass it to another function. like:

```
     sp_setup_point( setup, get_vert(vertex_buffer, i-0, stride) );
     my_test_func(i-0);
```

so I wrote two macro:

```
      #define GET_VERT(_x, _y, _z) get_vert(_x, _y, _z) , _y
      #define SP_SETUP_POINT(_x, _y, _z) sp_setup_point(_x, _y); my_test_func(_z);
```

and call them like:

```
     SP_SETUP_POINT( setup, GET_VERT(vertex_buffer, i-0, stride));
```

however, it does not give what I want, it expands to:

```
     sp_setup_point(setup, get_vert(vertex_buffer, i-0, stride), i-0); my_test_func();
```

and MSVC compiler complains

```
    not enough actual parameters for macro 'SP_SETUP_POINT'
```

I searched quite a bit, according to https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Argument-Prescan.html

> Macro arguments are completely macro-expanded before they are substituted into a macro body, unless they are stringified or pasted with other tokens. After substitution, the entire macro body, including the substituted arguments, is scanned again for macros to be expanded. The result is that the arguments are scanned twice to expand macro calls in them

the argument are fully expanded, but the additional argument is not recognized. how it that ? any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Hint: Use your compiler's option to emit the preprocessed sourcecode to see what the expression evaluates to.

Comment: Yes, I tried. I got the code after preprocessed, but still dont know how to get desired macro expansion.

Answer (score 1):

The reason, IIRC, is that GET_VERT *inside* of an actual parameter list gets only expanded *after* the enclosing macro call is scanned. So the PP first wants to see the ")" at the end of the parameter list of SP_SETUP_POINT. In this process it recognizes that it is one parameter short of the declared form. One level of indirection helps, but beware, macro programming in C is strange and suffers from early bad implementation choices that no one ever dared to correct due to massive compatibility debt.

```
#define GET_VERT(_x, _y, _z) get_vert(_x, _y, _z) , _y
#define SP_SETUP_POINT(_x, expandme) SP_SETUP_POINT_(_x,expandme)
#define SP_SETUP_POINT_(_x,_y,_z) sp_setup_point(_x, _y); my_test_func(_z)
```

The last form is better written as

```
#define SP_SETUP_POINT_(_x,_y,_z) do{ sp_setup_point(_x, _y); my_test_func(_z); }while(0)
```

because writing sg. like

```
if (a==1) SP_SETUP_POINT(setup, GET_VERT(vertex_buffer, i-0, stride));
```

will lead to invisible errors in the control flow.

Comment: Thanks for detailed anwser. I thought about it also, but no luck in this way. here is my version:

`#define SP_SETUP_POINT(...) SP_SETUP_POINT_IMPL(__VA_ARGS__)`


`#define SP_SETUP_POINT_IMPL(_x, _y, _z) sp_setup_point(_x, _y); my_test_func(_z)`

Answer (score 1):

If I was going to tackle this, I think I'd start from the desired output:

```
 sp_setup_point( setup, get_vert(vertex_buffer, i-0, stride) );
 my_test_func(i-0);
```

You have 4 parameters: `setup`, `vertex_buffer`, `expr`, and `stride`, where `expr` is the `i-0` parameter (which is itself a peculiar notation; how does that differ from `i`?).  I might use those longer names in production-quality macros; I'm going to use short names `a` .. `d` here.

So, I'd design my macro from that starting point:

```
#define SP_SETUP_POINT(a, b, c, d) \
    do { sp_setup_point((a), get_vert((b), (c), (d))); \
         my_test_func(c); } while (0)
```

You could then invoke:

```
SP_SETUP_POINT(setup, vertex_buffer, i-0, stride);
```

This would generate the code you desire, even in a context such as:

```
if (x > y)
    SP_SETUP_POINT(setup, vertex_buffer, i-0, stride);
else
    SP_SETUP_POINT(setup, vertex_buffer, i+2, stride);
```

If you don't use the `do { … } while (0)` notation, then you have to use a comma operator to separate the function calls:

```
#define SP_SETUP_POINT(a, b, c, d) \
    (sp_setup_point((a), get_vert((b), (c), (d))), \
     my_test_func(c))
```

This evaluates to the return value from `my_test_func()`.  There's no problem if you don't need to test the return value from `sp_setup_point()` — e.g. if it returns `void` anyway — and there's no problem if `my_test_func()` returns `void`.

You can also modify the macro to call `MY_TEST_FUNC(c)` and then conditionally define it:

```
#ifdef CALL_MY_TEST_FUNCTION
#define MY_TEST_FUNC(c) my_test_func(c)
#else
#define MY_TEST_FUNC(c) ((void)(c))
#endif
```

The advantage of evaluating `c` in the 'do not call' case is that the compiler ensures that `c` remains valid even as the code changes.  Do not under-estimate the benefit of that in long-lived code.

Comment: Thanks for another point of view. If I could not figure out the mistery of  the macro. I will adopt this way, It needs much invasive change of original code, so I am not taking it as best solution.